# algorithm to combine std::unique with a reduce step?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

can someone come up with a clean (and fast) solution to the following problem:

- I have a sequence of entries that hold basically a key and a value, say a

```
struct Value {
    int index = 0;
    int cost = 0;
}
```

- I now want to merge entries such that each key is only contained once but the values should be combined - i.e. each `index` should be only contained once in the sequence, and the `cost` for each duplicate index should be accumulated.

The basic solution I came up with sorts the sequence, and when equal entries are detected in the `BinaryPredicate` passed to `std::sort`, the `cost` will be summed into the `lhs`. Then the cost of `rhs` will be set to 0. Then follows a `remove_if` which removes the 0-cost values. See here for an example:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

struct Value
{
    int index = 0;
    int cost = 0;
};

// generate a bunch of random values in a vector
// values will have indices in range [0..10]
std::vector<Value> generator()
{
    std::vector<Value> v(20);
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), []() { return Value{std::rand() % 10, std::rand() % 10}; });
    return v;
}

void print(const std::vector<Value> &values)
{
    for (auto v : values)
        std::cout << "{i=" << v.index << ", c=" << v.cost << "}, ";
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// 
void merge(std::vector<Value> &values)
{
    // sort values and merge costs
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [](auto &lhs , auto &rhs) {
        if (lhs.index == rhs.index) {
            lhs.cost += rhs.cost;
            rhs.cost = 0;
        }
        return lhs.index < rhs.index;
    });
    // remove entries with empty cost
    auto it = std::remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), [](const auto &v) { return v.cost == 0; });
    values.erase(it, values.end());
}

int main()
{
    auto v = generator();
    std::cout << "generated values: ";
    print(v);

    merge(v);
    std::cout << "merged values: ";
    print(v);

}
```

[Live on Compiler Explorer](https://cpp.godbolt.org/z/EfbEGG58P)

Thing is: While the example above produces the correct results, it is from what I can tell not conforming to the C++ standard. A `BinaryPredicate` "shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterators" http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#8.sentence-4 . Compare is a BinaryPredicate. http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#general-2.sentence-1 )

Does this mean that my only option is to roll a custom `inplace_unique_reduce` or similar, or is there maybe an alternative elegant approach to this problem? I would prefer not having to write my own non-trivial algorithm for this.

Thanks

Comment: Please include the example code inline, not just via a link to an external, volatile resource.

Comment: Doing accumulation inside `std::sort` is a bad idea.

Comment: You could first sort, then process equal keys (which should be stored consecutively now), and finally remove all duplicate keys. 2nd and 3rd step might be done at once, of course. However, 2nd and 3rd step would have complexity O(n). Hence, I wouldn't care too much about the 1 or 2 extra loop runs.

Comment: @Scheff I would explicitly like to not have to do the extra loop.

Comment: @Evg yes, I gathered as much - that is why I'm asking here :)

Comment: Does it absolutely need to be done in place? Map would be a very suitable solution here, imo. Plus, how generic would you like a solution to be? In your provided answer the solution is quite generic, but it may be even more generic by specyfing some extraction function parameter (*projection*).

Comment: Yes, I want to do it in-place.

Comment: @milianw is there any additional requirements for input data? Maybe there is specific range of indices? or maybe there is algorithm which produces set of such indices? it will help to give better solution

Comment: I agree with Scheff that the most STL solution would probably be a two-phase (for_each+remove_if), after sorting. Then you could just use `Value* prev = nullptr` to keep track of the current value.index. With a huge amount of data, you could use a custom merge sort instead, where the merge also does the reduction.

Comment: @johv Custom sort might be good idea, I think I'd prefer a heap sort, though. Duplicates could be eliminated right on building up the heap. At least that appears interesting if the expected number of duplicates is rather high.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are ok with additional allocations, I would use `std::map` (or the `std::unordered_map`):

```
auto merge_entries(std::vector<Value>& original_values) {
    auto values = std::map<int, int>();

    for (const auto [index, cost] : original_values) {
        values[index] += cost;
    }

    const auto end_of_merged_values = std::transform(
            values.cbegin(), values.cend(), original_values.begin(),
            [](const auto entry) {
                return Value{entry.first, entry.second};
            }
    );

    original_values.erase(end_of_merged_values, original_values.end());
}
```

Apart from one `for()` loop (which *can* be substituted with `std::for_each`, although such change would introduce unnecessary boilterplate resulting in harder to read code, in my opinion), this solution uses only the STL.

We first merge all the entries using the map and then we overwrite some elements so that our original `std::vector` holds the merged entries. What's super convenient is the fact that `std::transform` returns an iterator pointing to the end of the inserted range. Why is it beneficial for us? Because apart from the unlikely scenario where no merging occurs, we have fewer elements compared to what was originally passed in. Using that iterator we can `erase` the rest of the vector (nonoverwritten elements) keeping it clean, STL-like style.

---

Assuming you are **not** ok with additional allocations, but you **are** ok with streghtening your iterator requirements (to bidirectional), I would use `std::partial_sum` and `std::unique`:

```
template <class BiDirIt, class BinaryPredicateCompare, class BinaryOpReduce>
auto inplace_unique_reduce(
        BiDirIt first, BiDirIt last,
        BinaryPredicateCompare cmp,
        BinaryOpReduce reduce
) {
    std::partial_sum(
            std::make_reverse_iterator(last), std::make_reverse_iterator(first),
            std::make_reverse_iterator(last),
            [cmp, reduce](auto acc, const auto& elem) {
                if (cmp(acc, elem)) {
                    return reduce(acc, elem);
                } else {
                    acc = elem;
                }
                return acc;
            }
    );

    return std::unique(first, last, cmp);
}
```

used like so:

```
auto values = std::vector<Value>{
        {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 7}, {0, 5},
        {3, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 10}
};
auto comparator = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return lhs.index == rhs.index;
};
auto reducer = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) {
    return Value{lhs.index, lhs.cost + rhs.cost};
};

auto to_remove = inplace_unique_reduce(
        values.begin(), values.end(),
        comparator,
        reducer
);

values.erase(to_remove, values.end());

for (const auto[index, cost] : values) {
    std::cout << index << ' ' << cost << '\n';
}
```

Just like your original answer, this will not merge nonadjacent elements, but to do that you either have to sort them by `index` or use something like `map`, from the first part of my answer.

The `std::make_reverse_iterator` calls are necessary becauase `std::partial_sum` accumulates the merged element in the most right-hand side one of given group of consecutive, equivalent elements. `std::unique`, on the other hand, preserves only the first element from such groups. Because of this, you want to merge the elements in the reverse order compared to the one you will be `std::unique`-ing.

---

You raised some concerns about situations where copying or moving is expensive - in such cases, you are either left with your custom solutions that take into considerations your unique constraints, or you ease your constraints. Here we move-assign merged entries, but that's it for the potential bottlenecks. If your move assignment operator is expensive, I fear that no standard solution will work for you and you **have to** roll your own, like in your answer.

Comment: This solution is nice from a readability POV, but sadly is strictly worse than my solution due to the additional memory allocations for each of the map entries. Furthermore, note that in a more complex scenario, splitting the Value apart into a key and value like you are doing is not easily possible (e.g. when the value is move-only). or maybe it's costly to do that.

Comment: @milianw imo your question lacks defined requirements a little bit. I prepared a solution with custom key extraction, custom value extraction, custom reducer, etc., but I just don't know the edge cases of your goal. It'd be really good if you showed more examples (e.g. what happens when you have third element in your `struct` - what happens with those when reducing?) In addition, I asked for clarification below your answer - your solution does not merge nonadjacent entries, while this one does. Should it?

Comment: Cool. Would it be possible to to remove the need for `reverse` by using reverse iterators - e.g. in the call to `partial_sum`? Anyhow, don't sweat to much about it, I'm fine with handing you the bounty unless someone else comes along with a fancy solution that we didn't think of so far. Personally, it seems like the custom solution I wrote above is best as it does the least amount of work. A pity really, that STL algorithms are so hard to combine to provide an efficient solution here

Comment: @milianw funny thing is that I just completed the edit where I mentioned that you absolutely can do what you just suggested with reverse iterators (gets rid of the reverse, but still requires bidirectional iterator). I will likely apply that edit to the code once I come back to my computer. As for the bounty, better wait for others to have their chances. It doesn't mean much - I am happy to help and dive into the algorithms :)

Answer (score 3):

This is the best I can come up with so far, but I still wonder if there is a solution that does not require a custom algorithm but instead combines existing ones:

```
template <class ForwardIt, class BinaryPredicateCompare, class BinaryOpReduce>
ForwardIt inplace_unique_reduce(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, BinaryPredicateCompare cmp, BinaryOpReduce reduce)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    ForwardIt result = first;
    while (++first != last) {
        if (cmp(*result, *first)) {
            reduce(*result, *first);
        } else if (++result != first) {
            *result = std::move(*first);
        }
    }
    return ++result;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, won't this fail in the case where there are two `Value` objects with the same `index` that are nonadjacent?

Comment: @Fureeish yes obviously, just like with a normal `std::unique`, you'd have to run `std::sort` before.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would be much happier to modify the objects inside the `Predicate` of `remove_if`, since it is a much simpler and more straight-forward algorithm than sort. It does require keeping track of the output index, though:

```
void merge(std::vector<Value> &values)
{
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [](auto &lhs , auto &rhs) { return lhs.index < rhs.index; });

    std::size_t o_i = 0;
    auto it = std::remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), [&](const auto &v) { 
        if(o_i > 0 && values[o_i-1].index == v.index)
        {
            values[o_i-1].cost += v.cost;
            return true;
        }
        o_i++;
        return false; });
    values.erase(it, values.end());
}
```

Here's another version using the range-v3 library (std::ranges doesn't have group_by yet).

```
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

void merge(std::vector<Value> &values)
{
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [](auto &lhs, auto &rhs) { return lhs.index < rhs.index; });
    
    auto merged = values
        | ranges::v3::view::group_by([](Value &lhs, Value &rhs) { return lhs.index == rhs.index; })
        | ranges::v3::view::transform([](auto &&vs){
                int index, cost = 0;
                for(auto& v : vs) { index=v.index; cost+=v.cost;}
                return Value{index, cost};
            });
    auto it = ranges::v3::copy(merged.begin(), merged.end(), values.begin()).second;
    values.erase(it, values.end());
}
```

Also, don't forget plain old for-loop:

```
void merge(std::vector<Value> &values)
{
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), [](auto &lhs , auto &rhs) { return lhs.index < rhs.index; });

    std::size_t j = 0;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
    {
        if(j>0 && values[j-1].index == values[i].index)
        {
            values[j-1].cost += values[i].cost;
            continue;
        }
        if(j!=i) values[j]=std::move(values[i]);
        j++;
    }
    values.erase(values.begin()+j, values.end());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that `remove_if` version definitely looks better than my original version. But it suffers from the same problem - the predicate is supposed to be constant according to the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/algorithms.requirements#7

Comment: The version based on ranges is not in-place, is it? I.e. there are allocations occurring for the `merged`, no?

Comment: Good question! I think it is in-place, but I'm not familiar enough with group_by or ranges (nor their implementation) to say for sure.

Comment: `j = 0; for(i = 1; i < size; ++i) { if(values[i].index == values[j].index) { values[j].cost += values[i].cost; } else if(++j != i) { values[j] = std::move(values[i]); } }` skips quite a number of operations.

Comment: `group_by` doesn't allocate anything because it only groups consecutive elements. This solution also requires sorting if you want to truly merge all elements in all cases.

Comment: @milianw the predicate of `std::remove_if` from this answer does not violate any requirements mentioned in the section of the standard you linked.

Comment: Also, since `merged` is a view of `values`, I am not sure whether `copy`ing one to another does not ultimately indicate that those ranges overlap (indirectly), resulting in Undefined Behaviour. Need to check that later.

Comment: Why do you say that the predicate doesn't violate any requirements? The link clearly says: "The function object pred shall not apply any non-constant function through the dereferenced iterator."

Comment: @milianw which operation from there exactly is a "*non-constant function [applied] through the dereferenced iterator*"?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what a non-constant function would be in this context. A function taking a non-const reference? We're not talking about side-effect free (pure), right?

Comment: @johv the linked quote from the standard specifically refers to the "*dereferenced iterator*", which is the iterator used to pass an argument for the predicate. In such situation, calling a non-const method on such element (assuming that we're taking by reference) would be UB. The predicate need not be side-effects free. It just can't modify the passed element to it (if it refers to the original element (it doesn't have to - your predicate may - in some scenarios - take elements by value)).

Comment: Regarding `merged`, I see what you mean. It is not allowed to copy totally overlapping ranges, but from e.g. [1,2..] onto [0,1,2,3,...] is fine. Then again, `merged` is not simply a view of `values`, it creates new Values on-the-fly. Not sure exactly how that factors in.

Comment: I don't quite understand the distinction. I doubleckeched and changing the elements of the source invalidates the view, so the very first assignment your call to `ranges::v3::copy` does, it completely invalidates the `merged` object.

Comment: Do you mean for views in general, or specifically for `group_by`? Where can I read about when a view is invalidated? Obviously e.g. changing the size of the vector (reallocation) would invalidate the range, just like it would for an iterator. Otherwise, I don't really know the rules.

Comment: `group_view` is not in the standard, but I found [the following for `filter`](http://eel.is/c++draft/range.filter#iterator-1): *Modification of the element a `filter_­view​::​iterator` denotes is permitted, but results in undefined behavior if the resulting value does not satisfy the filter predicate.*